# Are eggs (raw or cooked) and bananas acceptable as treats/emergency meals for dogs?

Tags: dogs, diet, eggs

When I run out of dog food my go-to is raw eggs/bananas because they're always in the house. Those are also my Pug's favorite food/treats. If I train her to do something new, or she's showing good discipline, I'll reward her with either. She has raw eggs every couple months and bananas as treats a couple times a month max. [Is this hurting her?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Tj2ejDmHOs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eggs are quite high in fat and not generally recommended to be given frequently. But using them for training purposes only is a great idea. Just remember this rule of thumb: Whatever human food you are giving your Pug, imagine the food amount being 3-4 times bigger and that is what you would be feeding to a human. Ever so often with bananas is OK. Once a week is all good and adult dogs can handle a little variety with small amounts of treats/human food ever now and again. Never feed the following though:

-Seeds and nuts of any kind
-Grapes
-Raisins
-Onion
-Garlic
-Chocolate (you'd be surprise how many people think a little is OK)

With the rewarding good "discipline", I'd try to move away from food if it's a general sitting when asked, unless you are teaching a new behaviour, than high rates of rewards to begin with and then fading to a verbal command and then to a hand gesture, coupled with the verbal command

Comment: I hadn't thought about imagining scaling up how much food I'm giving my dog. I've gone through a whole banana while training with each piece about the size of a human bite. I should divide it up into smaller pieces.

Comment: About the "chocolate" thing...  It's my understanding that dogs need to eat a percentage of their body weight for it to be dangerous.  If you're eating a candy bar and a small piece cracks off and falls to the ground, there's no need to freak out.  My Bichon has been cleaning up after me for years and he's in excellent health.

Answer (score 0):

A simple Google search shows both [bananas](http://www.pet360.com/dog/nutrition/can-dogs-eat-bananas/0h4luVaGiECXoAyYm4FmaA) and [raw eggs](http://www.dogsnaturallymagazine.com/feeding-your-dog-raw-eggs-good-or-bad/) appear safe for a dog to eat in moderation.

As always, you should check with your vet before feeding your pet something new.

Comment: As a kid I would on rare occasion eat a spoon full of butter. That's not acceptable even if it's in moderation. I wasn't sure if feeding my dog eggs and bananas was ok in the way that eating the rare chunk of butter is not technically life threatening or, more like having a piece of cake. It sounds like it's a closer analog to cake than to butter.